# What is this symbol called?

Tags: symbols

I have just found the following symbol in the book, Multidimensional Real Analysis I: Differentiation by "J.J. Duistermaat and J.A.C. Kolk. The meaning of the symbol is "a map from a subset of the domain to the range". I would like to know the latex code of the symbol.

[image]

Comment: What does `\kern-1.7pt` do?

Comment: It reduces the kerning of 1.7 points.

Comment: For reference, *kerning* is a word that refers to the amount of space between glyphs in a line; for example, `AVAST` requires different kerning between A/V combinations than it does for S/T.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I didn't find this symbol neither with Detexify nor in "The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List".

But it can be obtained with `\supset\kern-1.7pt\rightarrow`

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[\supset\kern-1.7pt\rightarrow\]
\end{document}
```

Result

[image]

If you want you can define a new command, let's say `\supsetarrow`, to simplify using it:

```
\newcommand{\supsetarrow}{\supset\kern-1.7pt\rightarrow}
```

---

### Edit from egreg's suggestion

Probably using

```
\newcommand{\supsetarrow}{\supset\mathrel{\mkern-3.1mu}\rightarrow}
```

gives better results in sub/superscripts, although not in second level ones.

Choose the one that better fits your needs.

Comment: Using `\mathrel{\mkern-3.1mu}` instead of `\kern-1.7pt` makes the symbol print properly also if used in subscripts and independent of the main font size. Of course, different math fonts (say `mathpazo`, `fourier` or `kpfonts`) may require adjusting the length of the back up spacing.

Comment: @egreg I've tried both and my solution seems to print better subsubscripts. Please let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: I get wrong results with your definition, but good ones with `\newcommand{\supsetarrow}{\supset\mathrel{\mkern-3.1mu}\rightarrow}` Try it at `\huge` size with `X \supsetarrow Y_{A\supsetarrow B}`

Comment: @egreg It seems OK in my viewer (Sumatra). Instead I get bad results with yours at normal size. Try `A \supsetarrow B_{A \supsetarrow B_{A \supsetarrow B}}`

Comment: I get better results with egreg's method on okular in subscripts. Otherwise, both work fine. Thanks a lot to both.

Comment: Right; unfortunately at scriptscript size the amount of backing up is insufficient. Unfortunately it seems that the fix should be dependent on the main font size because the result is good at larger sizes. However, using the symbol at second level subscripts or superscripts seems not so important; just remember that it could be not working in those places.